# How to change PrismaClient database connection at runtime?

Tags: javascript, prisma

I have .env file like

```
DATABASE_URL="sqlserver://srv:50119;initial catalog=mydb;user=aaa;password=bbb;"
```

and then schema.prisma like

```
datasource db {
  provider = "sqlserver"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["microsoftSqlServer"]
}
```

I generate a client using:

```
npx prisma generate
```

and then Prisma works great in my express app using:

```
const prisma = new PrismaClient();
```

Say I wanted to use a different db for user for multi-tenancy, how can I achieve this? Ideally I'd want to switch the db connection at runtime but it seems that DATABASE_URL is only read during prisma generate and not at runtime so the generated client ends up with a hardcoded db url.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [the datasource property](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#datasources) to create a new `PrismaClient` instance and pass a dynamic URL.

> **datasources**
>
> Programmatically overrides properties of the datasource block in the schema.prisma file - for example, as part of
> an integration test. See also: Data sources